# sbt-release publish artifact to wrong repository

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

So I'm trying to use [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release), and I'm having issues where it's publishing the artifact to my snapshot repository, and not the release repository.

```
val Organization = "com.mycompany"
val Name = "My Service"
val Version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
...
settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
  name := Name,
  organization := Organization,
  version := Version,
  scalaVersion := ScalaVersion
  ...
  assemblyJarName in assembly := s"my-service-${Version}.jar",
 ...
)
publishTo := {
    val nexus = "my.nexus.url.com/repositories/"
    if (isSnapshot.value)
      Some("snapshots" at nexus + "snapshots/")
    else
      Some("releases"  at nexus + "releases/")
  },
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
```

If I remove the `-SNAPSHOT` from the version, then it publishes it to the correct repository, but shouldn't sbt-release be telling it to do that by itself? 


Also if I get rid of the `if (isSnapshot.value)` then `sbt publish` will also publish to the wrong repository.


If I could get some help on this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It was the version I had here.  It was over riding the version.sbt which is where `0.1-SNAPSHOT` should be stored.